# String variables inside .css() method don't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am new to this so this could potentially be more simple than I think, but I am puzzled by this issue.

I can use number variables in .css() no issue, but a string doesn't appear to work. When testing, it simply won't do anything. Is there another way to do this?

```js
var align = "center";
$this.css({'background-position': align + ' ' + -bgY + 'px'})
```

Simplified, but this is what I am doing. **align** is the variable in question, where it would actually act as a parameter you can set elsewhere rather than just typing center in there or so. I have checked and the align variable itself is the correct value when trying.

Comment: Can you post your complete code and HTML so we can help further ?

Comment: Assuming you have a `bgY` variable, that code looks fine for setting (for instance) `center 123px`. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: the css not getting applyed, or not working as expected?

Comment: Given the question details, it should work as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/foeu53nx/ . Please check if $this holds the right value, as you might be applying the styles on a different element.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Look at this JSfiddle posted above its the same as my answer. Can you talk to this guy as well about what you are saying to me ?

Comment: try `$this.css({'background-position': align + ' ' + String(-bgY) + 'px'})`

Comment: @Cristian Sarghe Hmm that does seem to work there, but not for me. 

Everything else is correct because as soon as I remove the align variable and just type "center " for example, it then does what I'd expect again. Only when I use the variable does it not. I checked $this and it's correct

Comment: @Desix Then maybe check variable scoping (as I believe the relevant code base is different and larger than the question snippet). To be honest, I see no other possible issue if typing in `"center"` instead of using a variable works.

Comment: @Cristian Sarghe not sure if it's the best test, but console logging the value of align right after the css is applied shows the correct value.

Answer (score -2):

You can try formatting string:

```
var align = "center";
$this.css({'background-position': `${align}`});
```

Basically, everything you write between curly brackets in string with `` is js code.

Comment: This drops the second value completely. Just swapping out string concatenation for a template literal doesn't do anything (other than limit the browsers where it will work -- sadly, IE11 is still significant). *(not my downvote)* It's more readable (to me), but fundamentally doesn't answer the OP's question. Their string concatenation seems to be just fine, so it isn't the problem.

Comment: Much more readable as a template literal, unless you are not transpiling the code and need support for older IE browsers.